# Accessing typedef/using declaration inside a class template through a class instance (object)

Tags: c++

Below is a simplified code showing my problem.

*Yes I tried and I could not find any similar problem through Google.*

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    using TypeFromTemplate = T;
};

MyClass<uint32_t> & MyObject = MyOtherObject;
```

I would like to be able to get the templated type through something like `MyObject::TypeFromTemplate` or `MyObject.TypeFromTemplate` (both doesn't work).

I figured out something like that: `RemoveReference<decltype(MyObject)>::Type::TypeFromTemplate`, but it's a little messy to use it a lot.

*`RemoveReference<T>` does exactly what the name suggests - provides a `Type` without the reference.*

*This code is **very** simplified - my class takes multiple template parameters, which do not have short names to type out, the objects are declared in the header, and the source files are very interested in accessing the template parameters for their own declarations, otherwise I would not bother with something like that.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use *using-declaration* to alias your `TypeFromTemplate`:

```
template<class T>
using TypeFromTemplate_t = typename RemoveReference<T>::TypeFromTemplate;
```

which makes it relatively easy to extract the template type:

```
MyClass<uint32_t>& MyObject = MyOtherObject;
TypeFromTemplate_t<decltype(MyObject)> value = 0;
```

Comment: It’s unclear what the `type` is since I didn’t see its definition in the OP.

Comment: @康桓瑋 It's actually std::remove_reference<T>::type.  For solid templated code, I'd suggest using std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<decltype(MyObject)>> (in C++11-17) or std::remove_cv_t<decltype(MyObject)> in c++20.

Comment: @grekd :  You can't do template programming without typing long names.  You can always use `using`  to shorten names as needed to make your code more readable.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy That's why I described RemoveReference in my post, I didn't want to use std::remove_reference<T>::type as the Project is on "freestanding" host and has different "non-standard" c++ library implementation (technically maybe it's not actually an implementation if it is so different, idk...). I'm not sure what the standard c++ remove_reference exactly does, I didn't want to confuse anybody by using it. It also does not change the problem.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I'm trying to use ```using``` just inside class definition. I think that both ```MyObject::TypeFromTemplate``` and ```MyObject.TypeFromTemplate``` are describing what I am trying to access in a very clear way, even if the first one might be confusing because MyObject is not a namespace/class/enum, the last one should be allowed/work.

Comment: @grekd  I understand what you're trying to do.  There is just no way of doing it directly.   Everyone would love to be able to wave a magic wand at the code and have less to type,, but it is usually not possible when programming with templates :)  Aliases were added to c++ for creating short names  from long signatures.  It makes sense to use them.

Comment: @grekd  What I usually do when coding for embedded is recreate pafrts of the std that I'll need.  std::remove_reference<> does  just what is says.  It's a very simple template, with oine specialiation for reference types.  Keeping the names the same makes the code portable for unit testing, or use with a different compîler.

Comment: Besides, if your use case is for inside cpp files, decltype(MyObject) is known before compiling, and one definition of the alias at file scope should cover your needs.